# Hibernate query.list getting cast exception

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-server-2012

I am trying to connect to sql server 2012. by hibernate.

**sql query**:  SELECT top 3 P.*,v.* FROM TBLPOMASTER P join tblVendorMaster v on v.vendorid=p.VendorId where v.VendorCode=10001 and p.ApprovedStatus='Y'

I tried to translate HQL query as

```
List<TblPomaster> poMasterList = new ArrayList<TblPomaster>();
            String sqlQuery = "from TblVendorMaster as  v, TblPomaster as p  where v.vendorId=p.vendorId and v.vendorCode=:vendorLoginId and p.approvedStatus='Y'";

            Query query = HibernateUtil.getSession().createQuery(sqlQuery)
                    .setParameter("vendorLoginId", vendorLoginId);
            query.setMaxResults(3);
            poMasterList=query.list();      

            return poMasterList;
```

in the above code query is executing fine. But query.list() throwing  RuntimeException as  **java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long**

What is the solution for the above error

Comment: You might want to review the data type for the 'vendorCode' column

Comment: Could you post your hibernate mappings too? To me it seams you have mapped a database `char` or `varchar` type to a Java `Long` type.

Comment: @theMarceloR: vendorCode datatype is Long in model file. But I am sending vendorLoginId a string value. is this the problem?

Comment: query.getResultList() .. try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are retrieving a value from your database and hibernate is trying to convert that to a Long value.

Perhaps you have mapped this table column to an erroneously typed attribute in your model class. I'd check which text values are defined a 'numeric' within your class.

--
@theMarceloR: vendorCode datatype is Long in model file. But I am sending vendorLoginId a string value. is this the problem?

Change the attribute in the model config from Long to String and see what happens.

**SOLUTION:**
Sagar updated his code and now he's sending vendorCode as a parameter, the value is casted from string to long.

Comment: you are right. But  Instead of changing the model file I am passing long value(earlier it is string). Now the above code is working fine

Comment: Wait.. so did you cast the String to Long or did you change the data type of your 'vendorCode' column in your 'TblVendorMaster' table to a numeric value to match the configuration you had in your model ORM? What do you mean by "I am passing long value(earlier it is string)" -- I believe you meant to say: "I am _now_ passing long value(earlier it _was_a_ string)"

Comment: I am sending vendorCode as a parameter.Now I casted input parameter from string to long. your believe is right.. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can change your attribute's type from `String` to `Long`
2. You can cast the value to long:

   `Long.valueOf(String s).longValue();`

It is also recommended to get the results of your query with:

```
query.getResultList();
```